# Comparing values in two ranges in Google Sheets and counting the values greater than the other

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to solve a problem and I've been experimenting but can't get it to work. 
Suppose I have two columns and I am trying to count the number of rows where the value in the first column are greater than the value in the second column.

So if the values in `column A` are `2,3,3,5` and the values in `column B` are `1,3,3,4` then the answer should be `2` because `2` is greater than `1` and `5` is greater than `4`.

Any suggestions?

P.S. seems like I'm struggling to define a criterion to compare against that includes a value in a range.

Comment: Are you having a problem getting those values from a google spreadsheet or are you just trying to make a javascript function to go inside a google-sheets macro?

Comment: You could use `=SUMPRODUCT` for this, where you sum the result of testing if A > B.

Comment: Just in a Google spreadsheet. Without providing a sheet let me show it like this :

          A  B
Row
1.       2   1
2.       3   3
3.       3   3
4.       5   2

For just the first row I can simply test if A1>B1
But how do I sum for all the times this is true in a row?

Comment: Hi tehhowch, would you be able to show an example of your proposed solution? The way it's written I'm not sure if I follow...

Comment: [This link](https://anandexcels.wordpress.com/tag/sumproduct-in-google-docs/) provides a pretty good explanation of `SUMPRODUCT`, including examples that should be very similar to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A4>B1:B4), TRUE)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please edit your formatting. Don't just provide code: add some text to explain it.

Answer (score -1):

```
ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(A1:A4,">"&B1:B4))
```